# NextJS redirect slug wildcard

Tags: redirect, next.js, glob

I'd like to redirect URLs that regex match `-\d+` to a URL without that string.
This works with the last slug but for the ones prior.

This is my redirect code:

```
  {
    destination: `/my-path/:slug*`,
    permanent: true,
    source: '/my-path/:slug*(-\\d+)'
  }
```

This url: `http://localhost/my-path/subdir-one/subdir-two-123`

redirects successfully to: `http://localhost/my-path/subdir-one/subdir-two`

However this url: `http://localhost/my-path/subdir-one-3456/subdir-two-123`

redirects unsuccessfully to: `http://localhost/my-path/subdir-one-3456/subdir-two`

I thought the [`*` was to match the entire path](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects#wildcard-path-matching) and assumed  the regex to be applied on every route.

What am I missing here?